# Socket programming in C - Let browser drop a sent message

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm creating a simple proxy to filter websites, it's an assignment in my network class, so don't mind the filtered words ;)

It's working arguably fine, the only problem I have, is when the page which the user tries to access in the browser contains a "bad word". Since the response for the asked webserver comes in packages, the first one (most of the time the header) is already sent to the browser at the time the packet actually containing the bad word arrives.
When the proxy detects a bad word, it should redirect to a site given by my teacher. The problem is, the response from that new site of course has its own header, but since the browser already got one before, he sees this new one as simple text, and displays it as if it was a webpage.

Is there a better method to redirect, which solves this problem, or is there another way, like letting the browser drop the last received message?

Oh, and here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BACKLOG 10   // how many pending connections queue will hold
#define MAXDATASIZE 100 // max number of bytes we can get at once
#define PORT "1025"


// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}



int main(void)
{
    int sock_fd, new_fd, web_fd, re_fd;  
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    socklen_t sin_size;
    int yes=1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv, bytes_recv, bytes_sent, total_bytes, i = 0, x, showget = 0, showpart = 0, counter = 0;

    char getter[1000], link[1000], url[500], buffer[4096], *redirect;
    bool bad_content = 0;

    printf("Starting server.\n");
    //printf("Give port: \n");
    //scanf("%s", &port);
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }


    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
    {
        if ((sock_fd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1)
        {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1)
        {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (bind(sock_fd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1)
        {
            close(sock_fd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        return 2;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); 

    if (listen(sock_fd, BACKLOG) == -1)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }


    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

    while(1)
    { 
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);

        if (new_fd == -1)
        {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop ( their_addr.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
                    s, sizeof s);

        printf("\n--------------------------------------------\n"
               "server: got connection from %s\n", s);


//-----------RECEIVING GET FROM BROWSER-----------------------------------------------

        printf("server: Receiving GET from browser ...  ");
        memset(&getter, 0, sizeof getter);     
        if (!bad_content)
        {
            read(new_fd, getter, 4096);
        }
        else
        {
            while (1)
            {   
                getter [i] = redirect [i];
                ++i;
                if (redirect [i] == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        printf("Done\n");

        /*if (strstr(getter, "favicon") != NULL)
        {
            continue;
        }*/ 

        //showget = 1;

        if (showget)
        {
            printf( "----------GET------------\n"
                    "%s\n"
                    "-------------------------\n", getter);
        }

        memset(&url, 0, sizeof url);

//-----------EXTRACTING HOST----------------------------------------------------------

        printf("server: Extracting host address ...  ");
        i = 0;
        while (1)
        {   
            if (!(getter[i] == '/' && getter[i+1] == '/'))
            {
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;i++;
                break;
            }
        }       

        x=i;

        while (1)
        {   
            url [i-x] = getter [i];
            ++i;
            if (getter [i] == ' ' || getter [i] == ':' || 
                getter [i] == '/')
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        char host[strlen(url)];
        memset (&host, 0, sizeof host );
        i = 0;
        while (1)
        {   
            host [i] = url [i];
            ++i;
            if (url [i] == 0 || url [i] == '/' || url [i] == ' ')
            {
                break;
            }    
        }
        printf("Done\n");
//-----------CLIENT------------------------------------------------------------------

        printf("Starting client.\n");


        printf("client: Connecting to: \"%s\" ...  ", host);

//-----------CONNECTING TO WEB-------------------------------------------------------

        if ((rv = getaddrinfo( host, "80", &hints, &servinfo)) != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));

        }
        p=servinfo;
        for(p; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
        {
            if ((web_fd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                    p->ai_protocol)) == -1)
            {
                perror("client: socket");
                continue;
            }

            if (connect(web_fd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1)
            {
                close(web_fd);
                perror("client: connect");
                continue;
            }

            break;
        }

        if (p == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect, try again!\n");
            continue;
        }

        memset(&s, 0, sizeof s );
        inet_ntop ( p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr),
                    s, sizeof s);
        printf("Done\n");

        freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
        //fcntl(web_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

//-----------SENDING GET REQUEST-----------------------------------------------------

        printf("client: Forwarding GET to \"%s\" ...  ", s);
        i = 0;
        while (1)
        {
            link[i] = getter[i];
            if ( link [i] == 13)
            {
                counter++;
            }
            else if (counter == 2)
            {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }

        if ((bytes_sent = send(web_fd, link, strlen(link), 0)) < strlen(link))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to send entire GET...\n");  
            return 0;
        }
        printf("Done\n");
        memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof buffer );

//-----------RECEIVING RESPONSE-------------------------------------------------------

        printf("client: Receiving response.\n");
        total_bytes = 0;        


        while (1)
        {
            bytes_sent = 0; bytes_recv = 0;
            memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof buffer );
            if ((bytes_recv = recv(web_fd, buffer, 4096, 0)) == 0)         //receive part
            {
                break;
            }

            printf("Received part (%d bytes)\n", bytes_recv);

            if( (strstr(buffer, "SpongeBob") != NULL) ||            //checking for bad words
                 strstr(buffer, "Britney Spears") != NULL ||
                 strstr(buffer, "Paris Hilton") != NULL ||
                 strstr(buffer, "Norrk\224ping") != NULL )
            {
                printf("Bad site! Redirecting ...\n");

                //-----------CONNECTING TO WEB-------------------------------------------------------

                printf("client: Connecting to: \"www.ida.liu.se\" ...  ");

                if ((rv = getaddrinfo( "www.ida.liu.se", "80", &hints, &servinfo)) != 0)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));

                }
                p=servinfo;
                for(p; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
                {
                    if ((re_fd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                            p->ai_protocol)) == -1)
                    {
                        perror("client: socket");
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (connect(re_fd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1)
                    {
                        close(re_fd);
                        perror("client: connect");
                        continue;
                    }

                    break;
                }

                if (p == NULL)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect, try again!\n");
                    continue;
                }

                memset(&s, 0, sizeof s );
                inet_ntop ( p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr),
                            s, sizeof s);
                printf("Done\n");

                freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
                //fcntl(web_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

                //-----------SENDING GET REQUEST-----------------------------------------------------

                printf("client: Forwarding GET to \"%s\" ...  ", s);

                redirect =  "GET /~TDTS04/labs/2011/ass2/error2.html\r\n"
                            "Host: www.ida.liu.se\r\n\r\n";

                if ((bytes_sent = send(re_fd, redirect, strlen(redirect), 0)) < strlen(redirect))
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to send entire GET...\n");  
                    return 0;
                }
                printf("Done\n");
                memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof buffer );

                //-----------RECEIVING RESPONSE-------------------------------------------------------

                printf("client: Receiving response.\n");
                total_bytes = 0;        


                while (1)
                {
                    bytes_sent = 0; bytes_recv = 0;
                    memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof buffer );
                    if ((bytes_recv = recv(re_fd, buffer, 4096, 0)) == 0)         //receive part
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    printf("Received part (%d bytes)\n", bytes_recv);

                    //showpart = 1;

                    if (showpart)
                    {
                        printf( "----------PART-----------\n"
                                "%s\n"
                                "-------------------------\n", buffer);
                    }

                    bytes_sent = send(new_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                    printf("Sent part (%d bytes)\n", bytes_sent);

                    total_bytes += bytes_sent;  
                }   

                break;
            }

            //showpart = 1;

            if (showpart)
            {
                printf( "----------PART-----------\n"
                        "%s\n"
                        "-------------------------\n", buffer);
            }

            bytes_sent = send(new_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
            printf("Sent part (%d bytes)\n", bytes_sent);

            total_bytes += bytes_sent;  

        }


        close(web_fd);

        printf("Done\nBytes sent to browser: %d\n", total_bytes);

        puts("\nEnd client\n");

        close(new_fd);
        }


    close (sock_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Just get the entire response before sending it back to the client.  This also fixes the problem where a "bad word" starts in the first read and ends in the next.

Comment: `i++;i++;` looks suspicious. so does `memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof buffer );`

Comment: @indiv What happens if the bad word is spread across two HTTP 1.1 chunks? Even reading the entire response won't handle that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need to hold all the data in the proxy before you send any of it to the client. That means you're also going to have to understand enough of the HTTP protocol to know when the response is complete. If you're required to support HTTP/1.1, that means you'll need to support chunked encoding.

Also, your redirect is not legal HTTP. It has a request header, but does not specify a version  of HTTP that supports request headers.

You have a lot of other bugs including accessing an array out of bounds and using `strlen` to get the size of things other than C-style strings. You call `read` and throw away the return value, so you have no idea how many bytes you *must* send to the other end. Honestly, it seems like you are attempting a programming task that's well beyond your basic programming knowledge. Things like properly handling binary data come way before writing filtering proxies.

Comment: Well, that's true, I'm not a pro with C, and socket programming was an unknown word for me 3 days ago. We did not learn it at university, they just told us: "So, write a proxy. Go."
But thanks for pointing out some major flaws.